# React.js props for component

Tags: reactjs

Basing on this example https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/n47gckhr/light/ taken from React's official docs https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

1) If I were to create multiple `FilterableProductTable` and having to get the data from server, I'll have to place the ajax method in a parent component and pass the data to `FilterableProductTable`(as in the example) on initialisation.

2) Wouldn't it make sense to have the ajax method inside `FilterableProductTable` to fetch the data it needs(and be an independent component). But if do that I will have to make the data(products in the example) a state of `FilterableProductTable` and not props since props can't be changed by its own component. But making the products as state doesn't sound right.

So is option 1 better or should I go with option 2?

Comment: This article is relevant and may help: [Container Components](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005)

Comment: @BinaryMuse Thanks for the link. It gives a good idea on who should be concerned with getting the data.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is better than option 2 but using a flux pattern would be better still. The primary advantage of using a flux pattern is better separation of concerns. It is good to have your data logic separate from your display logic. This results in easier maintenance of your project.